Indian passport holder traveling to India with passport expiring in less than 6 months
I am an Indian passport holder traveling from IAD to Delhi on Air India at the end of June 2024. Just realized my passport is expiring in Dec 2024, so it's just shy of 6 months validity. I've read several articles related to this topic and I'm a little confused.
I read similar posts on Travel Stack Exchange. One person says "The six months passport validity rule does not apply to Indian citizens traveling to India." Another person refers to a "an exception to the 6 month validity rule", and someone else mentioned "TIMATIC system rules", but I don't see any official website with rules related to this. The official guideline seems unclear.
With only 9 days until my trip, I'm unsure whether to risk a tatkal application at the Washington DC embassy.

Can anyone who's been in a similar situation confirm whether they were really able to land in india without issues ?
Did you do a in-person check-in as web-check-in does not seem to work ?
Did you have to renew the passport in India ? Seems like return to the US may not be an issue with less than 6 months on passport
Did you face issues when returning to the US ?

Seeking more definitive answers for peace of mind. Please advise.

Does this answer your question? Can an Indian travel to India with 50 days before passport expires?

Hello. I have read several related articles . In this article, itsthey say it depends on airline , another person mentioned the airline makes decision based on TIMATIC system.https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/186076/indian-passport-holder-with-less-than-6-months-before-expiry-travelling-back-to/189725#189725. In this article , they had issues with web check on air india website. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159511/travel-to-india-with-indian-passport-having-less-than-6-months-validity?rq=1 .  In the link you shared, the traveler was going via Qatar.

Were these travelers really able to go without issues ?

"Seems like return to the US may not be an issue with less than 6 months on passport" But if you entering on a nonimmigrant status with a definite expiration date on your I-94, that date will be limited to no later than the expiration of your passport.

Does this answer your question? Travel to India with Indian passport having less than 6 months validity

Thank you for the comment. Yes seems like return to the US is not an issue. Trying to figure out if I will have have issue going to india. Hoping to get some real affirmations from people who traveled in my situation.

The answers to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/185810/why-do-passport-validity-rules-exist would explain why it wouldn't make sense to have such a rule: the point of requiring passport validity is so that it is easier to expel the person back to their home country if they overstay or otherwise misbehave.  That doesn't apply to the country's own citizens, who have the right to remain there indefinitely, even if they do misbehave.


Can anyone who's been in a similar situation confirm whether they were
really able to land in India without issues ?

You can land in India till the date of passport expiry. That is confirmed.

Did you do a in-person check-in as web-check-in does not seem to work
?

Some systems may not be programmed correctly. You can do in person checkin, if web checkin doesn't work.

Did you have to renew the passport in India ? Seems like return to the
US may not be an issue with less than 6 months on passport

You have to renew the passport. If you are in a hurry, apply in tatkal scheme.

Did you face issues when returning to the US ?

You have to use both old and new passport when checking in and entering US. as the visas for US in the old passport will be valid, even if passport is renewed.
